# public_html in address line on hosting

Tags: php, cakephp, hosting, cakephp-3.x

I have problem and don't know what to do.
This problem starts appear only on hosting. I'm using CakePHP 3.
On every action 'public_html' adds to address line. Something like this (look at screenshot):
https://gyazo.com/8474d1dd4ba50397e7c444f71845205b

I can't anything, because after i submit something and use 
$this->redirect(['action' => 'addnews']);
It redirects me to normal page without 'public_html' in address line, but i can't go to any other action, because they are not allowed for not authorized.

My routes:

```
use Cake\Core\Plugin;
use Cake\Routing\Router;


Router::defaultRouteClass('DashedRoute');

Router::scope('/', function ($routes) {

// USER Actions //
$routes->connect('/register', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'register']);
$routes->connect('/registernotification', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'registerNotification']);
$routes->connect('/unregisternotification', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'unregisterNotification']);
$routes->connect('/addudid', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'addUdId']);
$routes->connect('/removeudid', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'removeUdId']);

// News Actions //
$routes->connect('/newslist', ['controller' => 'News', 'action' => 'newsList']);
$routes->connect('/getfromcategory', ['controller' => 'News', 'action' => 'getFromCategory']);
$routes->connect('/favorite', ['controller' => 'News', 'action' => 'favorite']);
$routes->connect('/addtofavorite', ['controller' => 'News', 'action' => 'addToFavorite']);
$routes->connect('/removefromfavorite', ['controller' => 'News', 'action' => 'removeFromFavorite']);
$routes->connect('/search', ['controller' => 'News', 'action' => 'search']);


$routes->fallbacks('DashedRoute');
});

Router::prefix('admin', function ($routes) {
$routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'News', 'action' => 'login']);

$routes->connect('/:controller');
$routes->fallbacks('DashedRoute');
});


Plugin::routes();


My beforeFilter in NewsController:
public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
{
    if ($this->request->prefix == 'admin') {

        $this->Auth->deny();
        $this->Auth->allow(['login', 'logout']);

        $this->Auth->config([
            'loginRedirect' => [
                'controller' => 'News',
                'action' => 'addnews'
            ],
            'logoutRedirect' => [
                'prefix' => false,
                'controller' => 'News',
                'action' => 'login',
            ],
            'loginAction' => [
                'controller' => 'News',
                'action' => 'login',
            ],
            'authenticate' => [
                'Form' => [
                    'passwordHasher' => 'Default',
                    'fields' => ['username' => 'login', 'password' => 'pass'],
                    'userModel' => 'Administrators',
                ]
            ],
            'flash' => [
                'key' => 'auth',
                'element' => 'error',
            ],
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a misconfiguration at your hosting provider. Try contacting them to get rid of the public_html part.